# Activate Xhprof only in slow pages

Tags: php, xhprof

Is it possible to activate xhprof only after a -tot- of time after a page/url is called?

Normally I have pages that respond under 1 second. Sometimes they responde in 10 seconds (no, it's not the session on file). I want to activate xhprof after 1 second from the beginning of the request. (It's ok to lose first second of profiling by now)

If it was javascript, we have the setTimeout, but PHP is not threaded.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this. xhprofon.php:

```
function my_xhprof_disable()
{
    $xhprof_data = xhprof_disable();

    if(defined('MY_DEBUG_START') && (microtime(true) - MY_DEBUG_START) > 1)
    {
        $XHPROF_ROOT = "/src/to/xprof/";
        include_once $XHPROF_ROOT . "/xhprof_lib/utils/xhprof_lib.php";
        include_once $XHPROF_ROOT . "/xhprof_lib/utils/xhprof_runs.php";
        $xhprof_runs = new XHProfRuns_Default();
        $run_id = $xhprof_runs->save_run($xhprof_data, "mysitename");
    }
}

define('MY_DEBUG_START', microtime(true));
xhprof_enable(XHPROF_FLAGS_CPU + XHPROF_FLAGS_MEMORY);

register_shutdown_function('my_xhprof_disable');
```

Then use auto_prepend_file for include this file on all pages.

Comment: This will "activate" xhprof profiling in every cases (`xhprof_enable()` always executed), but only the output is going to be saved if you reached a certain amount of time. Depending on what the author means by "activate", it may not answer the question, especially if the goal is to not suffer from the performance overhead of a profiler on every request.